# Cross Reference fom 2 different DSL

Tags: xtext

How everbody,

I have an intriging scenario with Xtext and I am out of ideas, so I like to ask you.

I am actually using cross references from two different DSLs in my project but I can't figure of how to deal with following scenario,.

DSL1:

```
grammar com.test.DSL1 with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals
import "http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore" as ecore
generate DSL1 "http://test.com/DSL1"

Model:
   (elements+=AbstractElement)*;
   
   QualifiedName:
      ID ('.' ID)*;

   QualifiedNameWithWildcard:
      QualifiedName '.*'?;  
   
   AbstractElement:
      Base;

   Base:
      'base' name=ID
      'something' '=' (something=STRING)
```

DSL2

```
grammar com.test.DSL2 with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals
import "http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore" as ecore
generate DSL2 "http://test.com/DSL2"

import "http://test.com/DSL1" as dsl1

Model:
   (elements+=OtherElement)*;
   
   QualifiedName:
      ID ('.' ID)*;

   QualifiedNameWithWildcard:
      QualifiedName '.*'?;  
   
   OtherElement:
      Ceiling;

   Ceiling:
      'ceiling' name=ID
      'otherthing' '=' (otherthing=STRING)

   Plan:
      'plan' name=ID
      'element' element=[dsl1::Base|Ceiling]
```

As you might guess

```
'element' element=[dsl1::Base|Ceiling]
```

is not working.

If the Base and Ceiling would be in the same DSL, I would do the following and it will work..

```
AbstractBaseCeiling:
    Base | Ceiling;

Plan:
    'plan' name=ID
    'element' element=[AbstractBaseCeiling]
```

But

```
AbstractBaseCeiling:
    dsl1::Base| Ceiling;

Plan:
    'plan' name=ID
    'element' element=[AbstractBaseCeiling]
```

is also not working...

Don't understand me wrong my cross reference Setup is working because if I do the following everything works fine..

```
Plan:
    'plan' name=ID
    'element' element=[dsl1::Base]
```

But I could not figure out a way to use another Rule from another DSL and element can be either "dsl1::Base" or DSL2 Ceiling.

What am trying to do, is it possible? If yes, how?

Thx for answers....

Comment: what does not work with `'element' element=[dsl1::Base|Ceiling]`

Comment: Eclipse UI says 'The rule 'Ceiling' is not valid for a cross reference since it does not return an EString. You'll have to wrap it in a data type rule.'

Comment: ahh yes that is the semantic of  'element' element=[dsl1::Base|Ceiling] please note |something means "and parse a something"

Comment: if you mean an or you need to support this in the base grammar by introducing an abstractelement there and let both inheritfromthere or you need to refer to an EObject and filter the type in scoping

Comment: Base Grammar is really not under my control, so it would be big fight to change that. So what you mean with second option, I have to have ''element' element=[EObject]' then in the scoping to decide that is a 'dsl1::Base' or an Ceiling is. I can do that but it will be really annoying at Xtend Genreators an EObject, I would have to write lots of 'if instanceof'...

Comment: yes but there is no other chance to add a supertype to a type you dont have under control

Comment: what about making Ceiling a subclass of base?

Comment: Uhm what do you mean 'Ceiling a subclass of base', only way I know to do that is "AbstractBaseCeiling:
    dsl1::Base| Ceiling;" but that is not working also..or is there another way?

Comment: `Ceiling returns dsl1::Base: {Ceiling}'ceiling' name=ID  'otherthing' '=' (otherthing=STRING)`

Comment: Thx for the sample, i never really understood the return syntax :)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is two way to go around this:

- Either you want to share a grammar rule between DSL1 and DSL2, in that case see [grammar mixins](https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/301_grammarlanguage.html#grammar-mixins)
- Or you want to reference from DSL2 an element defined using DSL1, in that case you need to setup an import mechanism (see e.g. [a tutorial here](https://blogs.itemis.com/en/in-five-minutes-to-transitive-imports-within-a-dsl-with-xtext) but I'm sure there are others somewhere in the documentation)